# Problem about curves. A particle is running along circumference $x^2+y^2=25$

Tags: calculus, physics, plane-curves

I'm considering a problem about curves.
A particle is running along circumference $$x^2+y^2=25$$ with a costant modulus speed compliting a turn in 2 second. I need to determinate the acceleration in the point (3,4) starting from the equality $$\gamma(t)=5(cos\theta(t),sin\theta(t))$$.

I know the equation of the accelaration should be: $$\gamma(t)''=5(-\theta^2 cos\theta(t),-\theta^2 sin\theta(t))$$
I thought about determinate the angle from polar coordinates, however I'don't know whether it is a good idea:

\begin{cases}
p=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}
&&y=psin\theta
&&x=pcos\theta
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
p=\sqrt {3^2+4^2}
&&4=5sin\theta
&&3=5cos\theta
\end{cases}
In this way $$ \theta=53^° $$. But now i tried a lot of ways but I'm stucked.
someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: What does even "$\cos\theta (t)$" mean?

Comment: It is the parametric coordinate $$ cos\theta(t)$$, the variable parameter is t in natural number

Comment: Again, that expression makes no sense. What is $\theta$? It can't be a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\gamma(t)=5(\cos at,\sin at)$, where $t$ is the time. Since $\gamma(2)=\gamma(0)=(5,0)$, then $a=\pi$. Thus $\gamma(t)=5(\cos \pi t,\sin \pi t)$. Thus $\gamma^{\prime\prime}(t)=-5\pi^2(\cos\pi t,\sin\pi t)$.

Now, for point $(3,4)$, we have $\cos\pi t_1=3/5$ and $\sin\pi t_1=4/5$ for some time $t_1\in[0,2]$. Then $\gamma^{\prime\prime}(t_1)=-5\pi^2(\cos\pi t_1,\sin\pi t_1)=-5\pi^2=-\pi^2(3,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

The parametrization is just

\begin{align}
\gamma(t)&=5(\cos (at), \sin (at))
\end{align}

But what is $a$?

Well, we know that $\gamma(0)=(5,0)=\gamma(2)$, so

$$
\gamma(2)=5(\cos 2a, \sin 2a)=(5,0)
$$

Thus, 
$$
\cos 2a= 1\\
\sin 2a= 0
$$

And if we look a nice $a$: one between $0$ and $2\pi$, we see that $a=\pi$ works.

The acceleration is then

$$
\frac {d^2}{dt^2}\gamma(t)=5\pi^2(-\cos \pi t,-\sin \pi t)\tag 1
$$

Now, we want to figure out to which $t$ it corresponds the point $(3,4)$, but

$$
x=5\cos \pi t\\
y=5 \sin \pi t
$$

Setting $(x,y)=(3,4)$, we get

$$
 \frac 1 \pi \cos ^{-1} \frac 3 5=\frac 1 \pi \sin^{-1}\frac 4 5=t_0
$$

Plug that in $(1)$ to get your result.

Comment: It isn't the parametrization

Comment: @sinbadh What?${}$

Comment: By hypothesis, the first turn is at second 2. In your parametrization it is at second 1

Comment: Ah, right, I had not read that carefully. I'll fix it.